# If Cell in a range of values contains a type number print the corresponding header

Tags: excel

If I am given a range of values in a row in Excel. Each cell of that particular may have contents of type number or they may be blank. Is there a function/combinations of functions (Non-VBA) in Excel that will print the corresponding header of that type number cell (with a comma).

Furthermore if the cell does not contain content of type number then do not print that corresponding header and move on to the next cell. If it's the last value in the range, then don't print a comma at the end too. I would prefer it somehow do this in one cell that looks at the a range of cells then determines which header to print and which to ignore.

I'm using Excel 2013

I would like to do this without VBA. Here is an example below:

[image: Example Excel result]

Comment: is it just B-G columns? or do you have more?

Comment: This was an example, so there are more than 6 columns (20 columns) and its Excel 2013. I'm looking for a formula that's not repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I originally came up with this solution, refined it a little bit. I just wish it was less tedious and more accomodating in case I were to have more than 8 columns.

> =IFERROR(IF(M243=0,LEFT(IF(D243>=1,D$1&", ","")&IF(E243>=1,E$1&",","")&IF(F243>=1,F$1&",","")&IF(G243>=1,G$1&",","")&IF(H243>=1,H$1&",","")&IF(I243>=1,I$1&",","")&IF(J243>=1,J$1&",","")&IF(K243>=1,K$1&",","")&IF(L243>=1,L$1&",","")&IF(M243>=1,M$1,""),LEN(IF(D243>=1,D$1&",
>   ","")&IF(E243>=1,E$1&",","")&IF(F243>=1,F$1&",","")&IF(G243>=1,G$1&",","")&IF(H243>=1,H$1&",","")&IF(I243>=1,I$1&",","")&IF(J243>=1,J$1&",","")&IF(K243>=1,K$1&",","")&IF(L243>=1,L$1&",","")&IF(M243>=1,M$1,""))-1),LEFT(IF(D243>=1,D$1&",
>   ","")&IF(E243>=1,E$1&",","")&IF(F243>=1,F$1&",","")&IF(G243>=1,G$1&",","")&IF(H243>=1,H$1&",","")&IF(I243>=1,I$1&",","")&IF(J243>=1,J$1&",","")&IF(K243>=1,K$1&",","")&IF(L243>=1,L$1&",","")&IF(M243>=1,M$1,""),LEN(IF(D243>=1,D$1&",
>   ","")&IF(E243>=1,E$1&",","")&IF(F243>=1,F$1&",","")&IF(G243>=1,G$1&",","")&IF(H243>=1,H$1&",","")&IF(I243>=1,I$1&",","")&IF(J243>=1,J$1&",","")&IF(K243>=1,K$1&",","")&IF(L243>=1,L$1&",","")&IF(M243>=1,M$1,"")))),"")

It takes the length of the output and takes off the last comma at the end. I changed the rows to have zero's instead of just leaving the cell blank.

Although the above is ugly, this is obviously not the best solution without VBA, but it's the only solution I was able to come up with just using Excel functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way for this, **IF** the first column is always a number, or if you could live with a string that starts with a comma if the first column is not a number.

> =IF(ISNUMBER(F5);F4&IF(ISNUMBER(G5);","&G4;"")&IF(ISNUMBER(H5);","&H4;"")&IF(ISNUMBER(I5);","&I4;"")&IF(ISNUMBER(J5);","&J4;"")&IF(ISNUMBER(K5);","&K4;"")&IF(ISNUMBER(L5);","&L4;""))

If it is completely random which column contains the first number the formula you would have to expand the formula to include the second cell similar to the first ISNUMBER statement in this formula. This would then be placed at the end between the two closing brackets like such:

> .....&IF(ISNUMBER(L5);","&L4;"");IF(ISNUMBER(G5);G4&IF(ISNUMBER(H5.......)

Comment: Whether a cell contains a number is random, so the sequence will change. There's no way to do this with a range, in case I had 300+ columns that I had to deal with because entering isnumber( for all 300 items would get tedious.

Comment: @rossjohnson Well then you should have mentioned that in your question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate row to save the hell of copying and pasting the values.

In an intermediate row `6`, put this formula and drag it across:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B3),B1&",","")
```

Then, in an intermediate result cell `B8`, put this:

```
=CONCATENATE(B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6)
```

Now, remove the last comma:

```
=left(B8,Len(b8)-1)
```

Note that in Excel 2016, this is much easier:  the `Concat()` function means you can enter the cells to concantenate into a range:  `=concat(B6:AZ6)` or whatever.

Comment: If I had 300+ rows this might be overkill

Comment: Rows or Columns?  Anyway - I presume you're talking about entering the Concantenate functio?  To make it a little faster, start to enter the formula `=Concantenate(`, then hold down the CTRL key.  You can then click on each cell in turn, and it will be added to the list of arguments for the function.  Note that Concantenate is limited to 256 arguments, I think, so you may have to break it into two if you have more than this many columns.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it is very easy to do this using VBA:

```
Public Function Concatenate_if(valuesToConcatenate As Range, cellsToCheck As Range) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim sOutput As String
For i = 1 To valuesToConcatenate.Columns.Count
    If IsNumeric(cellsToCheck(1, i).Value) Then
        sOutput = sOutput & valuesToConcatenate(1, i) & ","
    End If
Next i
Concatenate_if = Left(sOutput, Len(sOutput) - 1)
End Function
```